# Should I use mathrm for these variables?

Tags: math-mode, variable, mathrm

I'm wondering if I read use mathrm for these variables below (relating to electrical engineering). They represents input, output or inductor voltages and ground.

Reading [the link](http://pleasemakeanote.blogspot.com/2010/07/italics-in-math-equations.html) I think I should use mathrm but I check many papers in the field and they don't use mathrm.

```
V_{IN} or V_{\mathrm{IN}}
V_{OUT} or V_{\mathrm{OUT}}
V_L or V_{\mathrm{L}} 
GND or\mathrm{GND}
```

Comment: never use math italic for multi letter names so either `\mathrm{IN}`or `\mathit{IN}` according to your style choice, but not IN

Comment: Besides checking style guides from journals so you for know exactly what to do, try to be always consistent and remember many people don't bother reading style guides at all. For example, if you write `V_{IN}` in your whole report, I won't think there are variables `I` and `N` multiplying each other, context solves this issue, but it if mix some `V_{\mathrm{OUT}}`, my [OCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_disorder) will naturally trigger. That said, using `V_{\mathrm{}}` is better than not using it, but not using it won't make your writings incomprehensible.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks, what do you mean by `but not IN`?  Using \mathrm looks nicer to my eyes but I was confused if it is good.

Comment: @FHZ Thanks, sometimes like in tables, mathrm makes it looking better to me.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle okay I think you mean not using `V_{IN}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consolidating and expanding on some comments:

The most important thing is consistency.  If you switch what you're doing, anyone who notices the switch will start trying to figure out the significance of that switch.  Even if you use the incorrect $V_{IN}$, as long as you're consistent, people will know what you mean from the context.

The problem with `$V_{IN}$` is that TeX treats `$IN$` as the variable `$I$` times the variable `$N$`, which has different spacing than the word `IN`.  If you want to have italicized letters, but the correct spacing, then you should use `$V_{\mathit{IN}}$`.  If you want to have upright letters, then you should use `$V_{\mathrm{IN}}$`.

This leaves us with the question of italic or not.  If there's a style guide for a journal that you're wanting to submit to, you have to follow that.  Otherwise, the link you posted is probably correct (but we shouldn't take some random blog post as authoritative).  But if you opt for italic, you'll be ok (after all, you were able to understand the many papers in your field).

Comment: Is it possible to measure the spacing between between `I` and `N` in `$IN$` and in `\mathit{IN}`, `\mathrm{IN}`?

Comment: No wonder why I complained that expressions like `$V_{IN}$` are bigger than necessary.